# How to show that $f(A)$ is an open interval.

Tags: functional-analysis

I was reading **Hanhn-Banach separation theorem** and it is written that

> " Since $A$ is convex ,open subset of a normed $\mathbb K$-linear space and  f is $\mathbb R$-linear and continuous so $f(A)$ is an open interval."

Since A is convex f(A) becomes an interval but why **open**?

Please someone help. Thank you..

Comment: Let $a\in A$ be such that $f(a)$ is an endpoint of $f(A)$.  Then some ball centered at $a$ is contained in $A$ and ...

Comment: Here I got the nice answer https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1811328/if-varphi-in-e-and-a-is-convex-and-open-then-varphi-a-is-an-open-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you already deduced it from the comments, but anyway, a simple argument:

if $f$ is non-zero then there is a vector $v$ for which $f(v)=1$. If $r=f(a)\in f(A)$ for some $a\in A$ which is open, then there is $\delta>0$ so that $a+tv\in A$ for all $|t|<\delta$. But then $(r-\delta,r+\delta)\subset f(A)$ as well.

Comment: I don't get why $a+tv \in A$ for all $|t|<\delta$

Comment: Because $a\in A$ which is open (and multiplication by scalars is continuous). The argument works in any topological vector space (no need for a norm as in the linked answer).